# Need Help in laravel asset() method

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-deployment

Here is my code in the controller :

```
    public function update(User $user)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'username' => [
            'string',
            'required',
            'max:255',
            'alpha_dash',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user),
        ],
        'name' => ['string', 'required', 'max:255'],
        'avatar' => ['file'],
        'email' => [
            'string',
            'required',
            'email',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user),
        ],
        'password' => [
            'string',
            'required',
            'min:8',
            'max:255',
            'confirmed',
        ],
    ]);

    $attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('avatars');

    $user->update($attributes);
    $user->password = Hash::make($user['password']);
    $user->save();
    return redirect($user->path());
}
```

In the User model :

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
 {
    return asset($value);        
 }
```

In show.blade :

```
<img
            src= "{{ $user->avatar }}"
            alt=""
            class="rounded-full mr-4 absolute"
            style="width: 150px; left: calc(50% - 75px); top: 300px"
        >
```

But when i go to the profile the image didn't appear and the link is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/avatars/JyDwtghw73u9hakMZEThiQfrj5AK33ZA1FOO47qN.png"

I tried to use mover() method instead of store() method and it's work, but move() didn't make a copy for the image in public 
it just link the image from it's original path in my device

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is the avatars folder inside the public folder? Should be placed in storage/app/public avatars, Otherwise its unaccesable

Comment: No it's not, it's in the app and the link is not working

Comment: php artisan storage:link

Comment: Same, the files are saving in storage/app/avatars
I write this in my .env files:
     FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
Still the same, i tried to change the path of storing in filesystem, but still the same

Comment: Like i said, you should force them to be in de storage/app/public directory. Move the avatars folder to the public directory if it isnt there and try again. If it doesnt work you have to check if you are storing it in the right directory.

Comment: I just need to change the store() path to save files !

Comment: Ya after i moved the avatars to the public the link works and the image appear in the web page, so i just need to change the default of storing, if i change it to store('public/avatars'), the link in database will be different and the asset() method will not work